# issue with parse

Tags: java, android

i have string that i need to make custom parser but i am stuck in braces that how can i parse this ....

```
[TPIN{PrimaryPIN=6152987; IsValidUser=true; }, TPIN{PrimaryPIN=794032; IsValidUser=true; }]
```

here is two field :

1. PrimaryPIN
2. IsValidUser

i got idea to get it in array with split but it not a good idea so can you tell me how can i make two array that can give me value of `PrimaryPIN` and `IsValidUser` please help me on this. ... .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple parser for the `PrimaryPin` and `IsValidUser`:

```
    String s = "[TPIN{PrimaryPIN=6152987; IsValidUser=true; }, TPIN{PrimaryPIN=794032; IsValidUser=true; }]";
    Pattern pinPattern = Pattern.compile("PrimaryPIN=([0-9]*);");
    Pattern vuPattern = Pattern.compile("IsValidUser=([^;]*);");
    ArrayList<String> pins = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Boolean> validUser = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    Matcher m = pinPattern.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        pins.add(m.group(1));
    }
    m = vuPattern.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        validUser.add("true".equals(m.group(1))?true:false);
    }
```

Comment: @user1381267 replace PrimaryPIN=([0-9]*) with IsValidUser=(true|false)

Comment: can you give me real solution which apply as in entire application becase this is talking aout single string and simepl data in future it will increase more and data will be complex so can you please give some solution that may be seems like parser

Answer (score 0):

Another solution based on @Paweł Nadolski's solution, but with a single iteration:

```
    String s = "[TPIN{PrimaryPIN=6152987; IsValidUser=true; }, TPIN{PrimaryPIN=794032; IsValidUser=true; }]";
    Pattern pinPattern = Pattern.compile("PrimaryPIN=([0-9]*); IsValidUser=(true|false);");
    Map<String, Boolean> pins = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    Matcher m = pinPattern.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        pins.put(m.group(1), new Boolean(m.group(2)));
    }
```